# How to send message to a specified channel

Tags: netty

im trying to use `websocketx` server demo in netty 4.0alpha8.

When i save a registered channel to a `static final DefaultChannelGroup`, it's easy to write message to all channels whith: `allChannels.write(message);`

But i want to write message to a specified channel with channel id, i used this:

```
final static ChannelGroup allChannels = new DefaultChannelGroup("registeredChannel");

public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.channelRegistered(ctx);
        allChannels.add(ctx.channel());
    }
```

And then i store `channelID=channel.id()`, try to write message to this channel with `allChannels.find(channelID).write(message);` but it does not work. How can I do this?

Comment: can you give more details about what not work? any exceptions etc?

Comment: Hi Norman , it was my mistake. I also changed my message to UTF8 then it works well now , the reason : my browser cant parse my message to a JSON object. BTW thanks for your reply.